# Android vitals bad behaviour reported because of too many instances of this crash: "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo"

Tags: java, android

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity ComponentInfo.

Crashes are happening only on devices running Andorid 12 or lower versions. I have checked other SO posts for the same issue, but none of the solutions suggested there work for me. Can someone help to identify how to fix this crash?

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@8329586: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7536745
at offset 33672 at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2962) at
android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:3344) at
android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:2501) at
android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2940) at
android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3261) at
android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236) at
android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1029) at
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.restoreState(FragmentStateManager.java:408)
at
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveStateInternal(FragmentManager.java:2512)
at
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1989)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1965) at
androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.kt:169)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3090)
at
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
atandroidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
at
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
at
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
at
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
at
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2884)
at
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:252)
at
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:220)
at
com.disha.quickride.androidapp.MyBaseFragmentActivity.onCreate(MyFragmentActivity.java:65)
at
com.disha.quickride.androidapp.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:198)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7967) at
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7956) at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3482)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3650)
at     android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
at     android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:151)
at   android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:111)
at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2213)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238) at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7853) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java) at    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:984)
```